# SQLITE: Show total (sum) for each category

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have two tables (inputs and categories):

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    iId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    sName TEXT NOT NULL,
    iParent INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (iParent) REFERENCES categories(iId)
);

CREATE TABLE inputs (
    iId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    iCategory INTEGER,
    dValue DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (iCategory) REFERENCES categories(iId)
);
```

I need get the sums(dValue column) from inputs table for each category. Even if the sum result is zero.

If is it possible would be better if I could get the sum for each Parent Category ( when `categories.iId = categories.iParent`, summing the results of the child categories to the parent category )

Can anyone help me? I appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Comment: In the second part (combining child categories with parent) - how many levels deep is your nested hierarchy of categories?

Comment: Is it possible you could provide a sample dataset with expected output that covers all the possible edge cases (parent with child category, parent without child category, category with no inputs, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select c.iParent, sum(i.dValue)
from categories c
left outer join inputs i on i.iCategory=c.iId
group by c.iParent
```

**EDIT :** With accounts:

```
select c.iParent, a.iCurrency, sum(i.dValue)
from categories c
left outer join inputs i on i.iCategory=c.iId
left outer join accounts a on i.iAccount=a.iId
group by c.iParent,a.iCurrency
```

Comment: +1 I wonder if by `Even if the sum result is zero.` OP means no inputs.  In that case should probably have `coalesce(sum(i.dValue), 0)`.

Comment: @mellamokb Right -- or perhaps `sum(coalesce(i.dValue, 0))`.

Comment: Now, I need to implement some Where clauses, for fields that are not described earlier. But when I do this, it's only returning the categories with inputs. See: `select c.iParent, sum(coalesce(i.dValue,0))
from categories c 
left outer join inputs i on i.iCategories=c.iId
WHERE  c.iType=0 AND i.dtDate BETWEEN '2012-06-01' AND '2012-06-05'
group by c.iParent` . How can I show all categories, but summing values ​​only when the conditions are met? Thanks

Comment: @Daniel Move the condition from the `WHERE` clause into the `ON` clause: `left outer join inputs i on i.iCategory=c.iId AND c.iType=0 AND i.dtDate BETWEEN '2012-06-01' AND '2012-06-05'`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You're the guy... One last thing, I promise. I have another table called 'accounts' and a column in this table named 'iCurrency'. In 'inputs' table I have the column 'iAccount' with reference to 'accounts' table. I need to sum ​​the values ​​in each category, but can't mix the currencies. Would have to be something like `accounts.iCurrency = 1` for example. Can You help one more time? Thanks

Comment: @Daniel Take a look at the edit. Now each category will produce as many rows as there are currencies with inputs in that category.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you a lot! One thing.. I've  copied your new code to SQLite Database Browser, then the program crashed. So I changed `left outer join accounts a in i.iAccount=a.iId` to `left outer join accounts a on i.iAccount=a.iId` and seems to be working now.  Is that Right? Thanks

Comment: @Daniel Yes, it was a typo: it should be `on`, not `in`.